# Why does this Python parser using parsimonious never find the ifdef blocks

Tags: python, parsing, peg, parsimonious

This is a simplified version of a larger parser. I has been driving me slightly mad as I can't seem to get it to work consistently.
The larger version works but has so many edge cases it does not work well enough, I'm finding myself having to teach python the entire syntax and all I want is the #ifdef pre-processor directives.

I tried to simplify it and got to this (below) but it never finds the ifdef / endif.  Why?

```py
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
CPP = Grammar(r"""
    file  = (code_block / nl / ws)+
    label = ~"[A-z_]+\w*"                         # Alpha or _ followed by alphanumeric or _
    
    ifdef = "#ifdef" ws+ label nl
    else  = "#else" nl
    endif = "#endif" nl
    
    line = ~r".+" nl
    lines = line+
    
    ws    = ~r"[\s\t]+"                           # One or more whitespace
    nl    = ~r"[\s\t]*[\n\r]+"                    # Zero or more whitespace followed by a newline
    
    if_block = ifdef code_block* endif
    if_else_block = ifdef code_block* else code_block* endif
    
    code_block = (if_block / if_else_block / lines)
    """)

code = """
int a;

#ifdef test1

a += 2;

#ifdef test2
a--;
#endif

#else

a += 20;

#endif

"""

res = CPP.parse(code)
print(res)
```

It finds many 'lines' but never a 'if' block.
(note 'code' is not suppose to do anything useful, it's just some sample text)

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667479/how-to-handle-all-possible-block-c-like-comment-styles-in-pypeg

Answer (score 4):

PEG parsing is essentially greedy, as parsimonious notes in its documentation. (This is not parsimonious-specific. You'll hit the same issue with any PEG parser.)

> `things*`
>   
> Zero or more `thing`s. This is greedy, always consuming as many repetitions as it can.

So you have a pattern for `code_block`:

```
code_block = (if_block / if_else_block / lines)
```

Suppose the parser is trying to match that at some point in the input. If the corresponding text starts with an `if_block` or `if_else_block` (more about this later), then that's fine. But suppose it starts with something else, like `int a;`? In that case, the parser is going to try to match `lines`, which is to say `line*`, which is to say *as many repetitions of `line` as possible*, as per the documentation above.

Now, `line` is just a line: any arbitrary sequence of characters terminated at the first newline. So `line` will happily match `#ifdef test1` or `#endif` or whatever.

In other words, if a match for `code_block` is attempted at some point in the input and the first thing in the input is not an `if_block` or an `if_else_block`, then `code_block` will greedily match the rest of the input.

Now, let's go back to matching `if_block` (and note that the same comment will apply to matching `if_else_block`). The rule for `if_block` is:

```
if_block = ifdef code_block endif
```

`ifdef` is a line starting with `#ifdef` [Note 1]. The next thing is a `code_block`, which as we just saw will greedily match to the end of the input (unless it happens to immediately match a nested `#ifdef`). In other words, `code_block` does not care that you would like it to stop when it reaches an `#endif`; it knows nothing about `#endif`. It's a greedy little monster chomping its way across your input. Even if `#endif` is the next line, it will get absorbed by `lines`, along with the rest of the input.

Since `#endif` can never be recognised, `if_block` can never match and the parser will have to fall back to the next possibility, `if_else_block`. But that can never match either, so it will have to fall back to the greedy monster.

In short, this grammatical model cannot work, and that's not the fault of parsimonious. If you stick to this model, it doesn't matter which PEG parser you use, you will end up with the same problem.

From the above analysis, it seems clear that any repeated match for lines needs to be aware of preprocessor directives, in order to not match them
[Note 2]. That can be done, but it makes things a bit more complicated because it forces us to categorise the possible inputs, and not just rely on ordered alternatives [Note 3].

So the key is that there are two kinds of input line: preprocessor directives (at least, the ones we're interested in) and everything else. (This is a radical simplification, because "everything else" includes comments and quoted literals, which need to be handled separately. But we'll ignore that for now.) It's easy to see how to recognize a preprocessor directive, so let's focus on recognising a line *which is not a preprocessor directive*. Fortunately, parsimonious (like many PEG parser generators) has a negative lookahead operator, which we can use to our benefit here:

```
line = ws? !("#" ws? ("ifdef" / "else" / "endif")) ~".*" nl
```

(Below, there's a correction to the definitions of `ws` and `nl`)

There's no need for `lines`, because of another issue I didn't note above. In the definition

```
code_block = (if_block / if_else_block / lines)
```

a `code_block` can be any number of lines but only exactly one preprocessor block. That's not right: a `code_block` can be any mix of any number of lines and nested blocks. The correct definition would be:

```
code_block = (if_block / if_else_block / line)*
```

It seems to me simpler to use a conditional in order to avoid having two different preprocessor block definitions. After all, both of them start with an `#ifdef`, and there's no point trying to scan that again after a fallback, even if parsimonious manages to do the rescan efficiently by packratting. So I propose the following:

```
ifdef = ws? "#" ws? "ifdef" ws label nl
else  = ws? "#" ws? "else" nl
endif = ws? "#" ws? "endif" nl

code_block = (if_block / line)*
if_block = ifdef code_block (else code_block)? endif
```

(I removed the redundant `+` from `ifdef` because `ws` already includes a repetition operator.)

At this point, a small digression to fix your regex patterns. The goal here is that `ws` matches any horizontal whitespace (excluding newline characters), while `nl` matches possible horizontal whitespace followed by a sequence of newline characters. But your `ws` pattern include `\s`, which in Python regexes matches any whitespace including newlines, which is a bit too generous. And while we're fixing regexes, `[A-z]` is not the same as `[A-Za-z]` because `a` does not immediately follow `Z`; they are separated by several punctuation characters (including `_`, as it happens, but also `[]` among others). The following isn't perfect either, but it's a start:

```
label = ~"[A-Za-z_]\w*"
ws    = ~"[ \t]+"
nl    = ~"\s*[\n\r]+"
```

So, to put all that together:

```
file  = code_block

label = ~"[A-Za-z_]\w*"
ws    = ~"[ \t]+"
nl    = ~"\s*[\n\r]+"

ifdef = ws? "#" ws? "ifdef" ws label nl
else  = ws? "#" ws? "else" nl
endif = ws? "#" ws? "endif" nl

line  = ws? !("#" ws? ("ifdef" / "else" / "endif")) ~".*" nl

code_block = (if_block / line)*
if_block = ifdef code_block (else code_block)? endif
```

That seems to handle your example code, at least.

#### Notes

1. This isn't really correct, because in C a preprocessor directive can be preceded with whitespace, and there is no requirement for the `#` to be immediately followed by the directive name.   But that's not the issue here.
2. *Warning: opinion follows.* Contrary to the oft-repeated advertisement that PEG parsers "simplify the grammar" by not forcing a division into lexical analysis and syntax, it seems to me that in many cases (such as this one), a systematic separation of concerns would actually be the simplest.
3. There is a place for ordered alternatives. They work well in lexical analysis, for example. But that's well outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: I used C as an example as it's more widely understood the actual language I am parsing is not C.

Comment: @JasonM: ok.  But I hope the analysis in the first part of the answer helps you find the solution to the question you actually have.